# Why is my button height not changing?

Tags: android

I have some buttons in a pop up window. I can adjust the button's width just fine but I do not know why I cannot adjust its height.
Here is part of my code:

```
    public void popup(RelativeLayout v){
            RelativeLayout r = new RelativeLayout(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            // w is the width of the device screen, tested it isn't 0
            buttonParams.setMargins(w/20, w / 10, 0, 0);
            Button ok = new Button(this);
            ok.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonshape);
            ok.setWidth(w / 6);
            ok.setHeight(w / 35);
            ok.setText("YES");
            ok.setTextSize(h / 50);
            ok.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
            r.addView(ok);
            p.setContentView(r);
            p.showAtLocation(v, 0, w / 4, w / 4);
        }
```

I understand that I can change the height by changing `(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)`
to specific numbers, but I do not know why I am able to adjust the width but not height with my code.

Comment: Please show where this w value comes from

Comment: Recommend you read this FAQ article for help asking this kind of question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: if you can read you have overrided your entered width and height of the button 'ok.setLayoutParams(buttonParams); '

Comment: @Ankush setLayoutParams changes the margins no? And if it actually does overwrite my width and height, then why am I still able to change the width?

Comment: params are used to add height and width. and more feature too like weight etc. check your layout after removing the above line and try to add some fixed height to the button.

Comment: @AnkushBist Well I removed it and it did not solve the problem;it only changed the margins of the button. Also I set my params to wrap content so I don't see why it should cause a problem

Comment: set the above params to relative layout and add the height and width to the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LayoutParams is created to handle size of child view inside its parent.
So i think you should

remove `ok.setWidth` and `ok.setHeight`

change layoutparams contructor to

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( w / 6, w / 35);
```

I tested and it worked. Please try !

Comment: But I set the layout params to wrap_content, and I was able to adjust the width with my code. Is there a reason why the width changes but the height does not?

Comment: I don't know exactly cause, but i think the measure phase of button handle this case, it will calculate the height of button again and your result appeared.